# How to make an image be inside a div of certain height and width, without giving the img element any height or width

Tags: html, css

How to make an image be inside a div of certain height and width, without giving the img element any height or width.Here is the html code

```
<div class="frame" style="margin: 0 0.3em; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  <img id="photo" src="images/minnie-mouse-cartoon-wallpaper-600x600.jpg">
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5hLh/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-width` and `max-height` to img

```
img{
  max-width:100%; 
  max-height:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ucOqUjaB/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS

```
div{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Siberian-Tiger-Running-Through-Snow-Tom-Brakefield-Getty-Images-200353826-001.jpg" />
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mVtJc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `img` `height` and `width` as `100%` and set your required `height` and `width` in your div

This way it will same size of its parent.

Check out his [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R5JF4/)

Answer (score 0):

Child elements will always reference their parent when you declare height and width in percentage. The image element in your example is a child to the div:

```
<div class="frame">
    <img id="photo" src="http://hulza.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/brave_still_3.jpg" />
</div>
```

I moved the styles to a separate CSS sheet, JSFiddle was giving me issues with the inline styling:

```
.frame{
    margin: 0 0.3em;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}

#photo{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I used *max* height and width because if the aspect ratio of the parent is incorrect the image won't render. With the max prefix, the image will resize itself to fit within the space given and maintain its aspect ratio. Both cases are in the JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/LDJGj/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/LDJGj/2/